# fetch data from SQL dbs and render to screen with pygame

Tags: python, sqlite, pygame

im implementing a leaderboard system; the way I have approached it is by using sqlite3, where i fetch all of the records from the database and then 'untangle' them from their array and blit them to the surface. I am having trouble with blitting them, I do not know how to get them to all display down the screen like a leaderboard would. 
code:

```
def lbButton(self, action='leaderboard'):
    self.leaderboardMenu = True
    if self.x + self.buttonWidth > self.mousePos[0] > self.x and self.y + self.buttonHeight > self.mousePos[1] > self.y:
        if self.mouseClick[0] == 1:
            if action == 'leaderboard':
                image = pg.image.load('leaderboardImg.jpg')
                while self.leaderboardMenu:
                    for event in pg.event.get():
                        if event.type == QUIT:
                            self.quitButton()
                        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                                self.leaderboardMenu = False

                    self.surface.blit(image, (0, 0))
                    #tempName = ''
                    #tempScore = ''
                    getData = c.execute("SELECT * FROM names where name = name ORDER BY score DESC")  # get so highest score is first
                    getData = getData.fetchall()  # fetch all
                    for _ in getData:
                        getData = [_ for y in getData for y in _]  # fetchall returns data in form: [(name, score), (name, score)],
                        # so using this loop 'untangles' that array and makes it so i can get the name and score individually
                        names = getData[0][0]
                        scores = str(getData[0][1])
                        print(names)

                    namesFont = pg.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 20)
                    namesText = namesFont.render(names, 1, COLOUR_RED)
                    self.surface.blit(namesText, (400,400))
                    scoresFont = pg.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 20)
                    scoresText = scoresFont.render(scores, 1, COLOUR_RED)
                    self.surface.blit(scoresText, (400, 400))
                    pg.display.update()
```

what the leaderboard looks like atm: https://i.stack.imgur.com/goqLL.png
result if I print 'names'(along with database records): https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmAhc.png (names print infinitely)
any help would be appreciated. thanks
(rest of code works, just blitting the records to the screen is the issue.)

Comment: Your `getData` loop looks very strange to me. Perhaps `for (name, score) in getData.fetchall():` would be cleaner. Please create a [mcve] so it's easier to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

So you're blitting the rows of text on top of each other, they are always draw to the co-ordinates (`400`, `400`).

```
self.surface.blit(scoresText, (400, 400))
```

So generally when writing multi-line text in PyGame, the code has to render each line to a bitmap, determine the height, and then use that to space the text down the screen.  Consider the function:

```
def getFontHeight( test_font ):
    text_height = 0
    test_bitmap = test_font.render( "WQ|^yg!`_", True, (0,0,0) )
    text_height = test_bitmap.get_height()
    return text_height
```

It uses a piece of text that contains both [ascenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)) and [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) to get a *rough* idea of how high any piece of rendered text should be.  This is important because the bitmap-height of `___` is different to `XXX`, and using the line height of each bitmap will produce an uneven result.

Once the code has an idea of how much vertical space to allocate for each line, it's fairly easy to space the rows of text on-screen:

```
names_font  = pg.font.SysFont( 'comicsansms', 20 )
scores_font = pg.font.SysFont( 'comicsansms', 20 )

...

def renderLeaderboard( screen, leaderboard, position, name_font, scores_font, column2at=400, spacer=5 ):
    names_font_height  = getFontHeight( name_font )
    scores_font_height = getFontHeight( scores_font )
    line_height        = max( names_font_height, scores_font_height )

    name_column  = position[0]
    row          = position[1]
    score_column = name_column + column2at

    for name, score in leaderboard:
        name_text = name_font.render( name, True, NAME_COLOUR )
        score_text= score_font.render( score, True, SCORE_COLOUR )
        screen.blit( name_text, ( name_column, row ) )
        screen.blit( score_text, ( score_column, row ) )
        row += line_height + spacer
```

Basically the code writes the name and score in columns, then increases the vertical offset (down the screen) by the font-height plus a spacer, drawing each line in turn.